# How to login to ubuntu from remote when no user has logged into system

Tags: ssh, xorg, remote-desktop, vnc, xserver

I was have setup remote login to ubuntu using VNC over ssh by using steps mentioned in below link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC#accessing-your-pc

I am using RealVNC viewer for this.

Now issue is, if remote ubuntu machine is logged off, It is not possible to login remotely. Is there way to get around this problem ?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong methods here. If the machine you wish to VNC into is not up and running, then it will fail because you are effectively taking over control of an up and running desktop. It is not the same as remote logging in to a server as described in this link: https://vitux.com/how-to-remotely-manage-a-ubuntu-server-with-ssh/

Comment: Ubuntu machine is up and running. I can ssh into it. But I am not allowed to get full access to remote desktop. You are right ssh is not same as remote logging into a server. My question is how do I login(remotely) into system and then connect to remote desktop?

Comment: This should help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327532/how-to-remotely-log-in-with-full-graphical-desktop-over-x11